# A newbie question about SPI settings for an STM32 microcontroller board

Tags: stm32, spi

I want to control [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8554.pdf?ts=1648208815441&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) DAC's output via SPI protocol using an [STM32 board](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf). To initialize SPI3 in my case I use STM32CubeMX. And under SPI settings I couldn't relate the settings to the DAC's SPI timing diagram. DAC's SPI timing diagram is given as follows:

[image]

In my case I don't need to receive any data but just send it to DAC so I chose the mode as follows:

[image]

My problem is under Configuration setting the correct CPOL and CPHA:

[image]

**1-)** How can we interpret the diagram in this case to figure out whether CPOL is 'Low' or 'High' and CPHA is '1 Edge' or '2 Edge'. What should those be in this case?

**2-)** I only want to send data through SPI and control only single DAC device. In that case should I still use DAC's SYNC pin, or would that be fine just to ground it? I'm asking because STM32CubeMX did not create any SYNC pin:

[image]

Comment: About SYNC pin of the DAC - that's totally up to DAC, check its datasheet, it has to explain what exactly that pin does, how to use it and whether you need it at all (and what to do with it if you don't need it). You may need to use GPIO with it - or maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should look at the chip reference manual to find out how to match CPOL and CPHA to your SPI device.
2. The SYNC pin is needed to latch data in to DAC when needed, so you can't just ground it. SPI does not have a pin with that name, but the name is irrelevant, as the SPI does have a pin with the name of chip select or NSS or whatever which you can use for the same purpose.

Typically Any GPIO pin will do and you have to control it yourself, unless you use hardware NSS but the hardware NSS may or may not be compatible. So check the reference manual if hardware NSS can be used, or just use GPIO pin yourself.

Comment: The thing is I already looked for it and couldnt figure out h CPOL and CPHA. I thought someone can figure out and answer my explicit question.

Comment: Why you could not figure it out, what problem you encountered? Open reference manual, look at SPI peripheral section, see CPOL/CPHA diagrams, find a match with DAC diagram?

Comment: Yes, what those mean are explained in the reference manual with diagrams.

Comment: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You're talking not so much about STM32's SPI, but rather about SPI itself. SPI offers options in terms of what idle state of the line is (LOW/Zero polarity = 0 IDLE state, HIGH/1 polarity = 1 IDLE state), and phase - data is read on the first or second edge of the clock from IDLE state. The combination of these two parameters is often called a "mode":

[image]

[Image 1 Source](https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters-group/data-converters/f/data-converters-forum/772490/faq-ads129x-what-are-the-correct-polarity-and-phase-cpol-cpha-spi-settings)

[image]

[Image 2 Source](http://quanser-update.azurewebsites.net/quarc/documentation/spi_protocol.html)

Absolute majority of SPI devices - but not all - work in mode 0, which is polarity 0 phase 0 (POL0 first edge). In order to see what kind of mode (combination of polarity/edge) you need, you need to find it in the datasheet of the slave device, since MCU master can work in any mode.

As for SYNC signal, it's some special function of the DAC, so you need to read its datasheet to see whether you can avoid using it all and how to terminate it if it's not in use (could be "leave floating", "tie to Vdd" or "tie to GND", for instance). It's not a part of SPI, and if you end up having to use it, you will most likely have to control it with dedicated GPIO pin.

You have some DAC-datasheet-reading work cut out for you.

Comment: So you are not gonna reply my questions. Read the data sheet is not an answer. I did that already. My questions are clear and this is a QA site afaik.

Comment: @ty_1917 do you want a fish or do you want to learn to fish? Looks to me like Ilya has told you everything you need here to learn to fish ...

Comment: My question is clear and you are not answering it. That is it. Thanks for advices anyways,.

Comment: Each MCU has their own notation for what CPOL and CPHA do, so it will not help posting generic pictures from different MCUs. The real answer is in the STM32 reference manual.